# Dual booting 12.04 on windows 7, partion i made for ubuntu is not showing up on windows explorer

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive

[image: Windows explorer showing some drives]

I made a 400 GB partition for Ubuntu.

[image: Disk Management MMC snap-in]

Why isn't the partion showing up in Windows Explorer? Should I be worried or is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows can't mount Ubuntu's EXT filesystem by default, so what you see is perfectly normal. Windows utilities can see the partition, but they can't interpret the files inside.

Generally, if people want to share files between Windows and Linux colocated on the same disc, they create a third, "neutral" partition in a compatible format: usually FAT. That way, both Linux and Windows can read from the shared space.

Comment: Thanks so much man. This was probably answered in another thing, but i could not find it, sor i'm sorry for that. I would tryt o give you a thumbs up, but i can't :( so thank you!!

Comment: You can mount `EXT` filesystems on Windows with [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=2) driver.